# How to imply swin transformer to arbitrary image size? ( tensorflow, keras )

Tags: tensorflow, keras, transformer-model

I am studying about image swin transformer(https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content/ICCV2021/papers/Liu_Swin_Transformer_Hierarchical_Vision_Transformer_Using_Shifted_Windows_ICCV_2021_paper.pdf) ,

and mainly try to follow swinIR(https://arxiv.org/pdf/2108.10257.pdf) that make super-resolution-ed image using swin transformer.

However, The examples and code I found only describes in the case that the image has fixed size(224 x 224 x 3 e.g.) And I cannot understand how the transformer block is adjusted for arbitrary sized image inputs. I am mainly referring the author's github https://github.com/JingyunLiang/SwinIR/blob/main/models/network_swinir.py

Please somebody tell me how and thank you very much .